# Extreme points of a set of bounded increasing functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am interested in the extreme points of the set of functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ is weakly increasing and  $f(x)\in[0,1]$.

I understand why the extreme points include only functions which step from $0$ to $1$ at some point $x^*$. But what about the value *at* $f(x^*)$?

Am I correct that in ${L}^1$, $f(x^*)$ can take on any value in [0,1] and still be an extreme point since functions which differ only at $x^*$ are equivalent in this space?

What about in ${L^\infty}$?

Comment: What do you mean by weakly increasing? Is this different from non-decreasing? Also what is meant by extreme points of the set of functions?

Comment: That seems wrong. It seems to me that $f(x^{*})$ needs to be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Yes, by weakly increasing I mean non-decreasing. By extreme point I mean that the point can be removed from the set and the set remains convex.

Comment: Can someone kindly explain why the extreme points are step functions? Unlike the OP I don't understand this. I've also posted a related question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485684/extreme-points-of-a-set-of-bounded-increasing-functions-with-euclidean-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$   given by 
$$
f(x) =\cases{0,& $0\le x<\alpha$;\cr \beta,&$x=\alpha$;\cr 1,&$\alpha<x\le 1$\cr}
$$
(where $0<\alpha,\beta<1$) is the convex combination $(1-\beta)g+{\beta}f$ of
$$
g(x) =\cases{0,& $0\le x\le\alpha$;\cr  1,&$\alpha<x\le 1$\cr}
$$
and
$$
h(x) =\cases{0,& $0\le x<\alpha$;\cr   1,&$\alpha\le x\le 1$.\cr}
$$
This $f$ is therefore *not* extreme.

Comment: In $L^1$ aren't $g$ and $h$ equivalent? I've updated the question to clarify and expand a bit.

Comment: @CommonerG : Why were you concerned about the value of $f$ at all if you were working in $L^1$? That makes no sense.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean it is meaningless in the sense that the value of the function at just one point does not affect the geometry in this space?

Comment: @CommonerG : Elements of $L^1$ are equivalence classes of functions, not functions. The value of $f\in L^1[0,1]$ at $x\in[0,1]$ has no meaning.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.