# Extreme points of a set of bounded increasing functions with Euclidean domain

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

My question is highly related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601015/extreme-points-of-a-set-of-bounded-increasing-functions).

What are the extreme points of the set of functions $f:[0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]$, such that $f$ is weakly increasing in each of its components? Unfortunately unlike the author of the linked question - which is the same question for $n=1$ - I do not understand why they are step functions in case of $n=1$ either. However I do know this to be true.

Generalizing the intuition for the $n=1$ case, I am trying to show that these are of the form $\mathbb{1}(\phi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\geq k)$ where $\phi(\cdot)$ is a function weakly increasing in each component. But this intuition might be wrong, of course.

Thank you for your help.

Update 1: I have been able to show that extreme points are indicator functions (or constant 0 or 1) but I'm not able to show the existence of a $\phi$ as I specified. I'm trying to show that if an extreme point is $\mathbb{1}_E$ where both $E$ and $[0,1]^2 \setminus E$ have non-empty interiors, then both $E$ and $[0,1]^2 \setminus E$ are simply connected. I don't know if this  is the  right path but I'm not able to show this either.

Update 2: Under the partial order $\geq$ on $[0,1]^n$ that for $x, y \in [0,1]^n, x \geq y$ if each component of $x$ is as large as the corresponding component of $y$, $E$ as described above must be an [upper set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set). Now take the set of all minimal elements (per $\geq$) of $E$. I think what I need to show is there exists a single [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Stronger_forms_of_connectedness) which connects all of these minimal elements of $E$. And that will, I think, somehow give me the $\phi$ I'm looking for. I may be completely wrong, of course.

Comment: What is 'weakly increasing'?

Comment: For any $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x,y_2) \geq f(x,y_1)$ for $y_2 > y_1$ and analogously for $x_2>x_1$ for any fixed $y$.

Comment: I have been able to show that extreme points are indicator functions (or constant 0 or 1) but I'm not able to derive the form of $\phi$ as I specified.

Comment: If you know that $f$ is a characteristic, then you could set $\phi:=f$ and $k=1/2$.

Comment: Wow that opened my eyes quite a bit. Thanks! But wouldn't that be circularly defining $1_E$? But as you can sense, I'm looking for a form something like $1_{(x+y \geq 1)}$ - I think I'm not able to specify it precisely. Would continuity of $\phi$ do it? I doubt that is true... Thanks so much already though.

Comment: I made some further edits to the question trying to make things as precise as I can (though still not fully precise).